# jQuery Sortable - Move item to top of list if dragged out.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Hi I am using jQuery Sortable, I have two lists which are filled with banners and the order of the banners in the "Selected Banners" are able to be changed. We have 3 sets of banners:

- Default Banners (Set by Company and is mandatory unless 2 or more selected)
- Special Banners (Set by company but no mandatory)
- Selectable Banners (General banners available for selection)

I have two lists one called Available Banners and the Other Called Selected Banners. The Default Banners are defined in red and can be removed if two or more are present.

However when I remove these default banners they are either placed at the bottom of the list of they are placed in the position I place them, depending on the precision of the drop.

Is their a way using jQuery I can move all items with the class name of defaultbanner to the top of the list in #sortable2?

My code is below or you can view my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gutigrewal/J9eQL/1/)

JS.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
    $("#sortable1").sortable({
      cancel: ".ui-state-disabled",
      handle: ":not(input)"
    });

  $("#sortable2").sortable({
        cancel: ".ui-state-disabled",
          receive: function (event, ui) {
           if (ui.item.hasClass("defaultbanner")) {
           $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
           alert("This is a default banner, it can be sorted but not removed.");
       }
   }
      });

  //new function to define that if a Partner has more than 2 selectable banners then the defaultbanner. If less than two selectable banners than the default banner cannot be

  $("#sortable2").sortable({
    cancel: ".ui-state-disabled",
      receive: function (event, ui) {
       if (ui.item.hasClass("defaultbanner") && $('#sortable1 li').length <= 1) {
           $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
           alert("This is a default banner, it can be sorted but not removed.");
       }
       else if($('#sortable1 li').length <= 1) {
          $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
          alert('You must have at least two banners');    
      }
       }
  });

  $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
  }).disableSelection();

  $("#sortable1 li,#sortable2 li").disableSelection();

  // no more than 7 banners allowed 
  $("#sortable1").sortable({
        connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
        //receive: This event is triggered when a connected sortable list has received an item from another list.
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            // so if > 7
            if ($(this).children().length > 7) {
                //ui.sender: will cancel the change. Useful in the 'receive' callback.
            $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
            alert('Your selection has been cancelled. A maximum 7 banners are allowed in the carousel.');
        }
        if ( $('#sortable1 .selectablebanner').length > 4) {
            alert('Your selection has been cancelled. A maximum 4 custom banners are allowed in the carousel.');
            $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
        }  
    }
}).disableSelection();
});

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just add a pseudo `sorting` function as the last call of `receive`

```
function doSortMe(){
        console.log('sorting');
         $('#sortable2').prepend($('#sortable2 .defaultbanner'));  
    }
/////    .....
        $("#sortable2").sortable({
            cancel: ".ui-state-disabled",
            receive: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item.hasClass("defaultbanner") && $('#sortable1 li').length <= 1) {
                    $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
                    alert("This is a default banner, it can be sorted but not removed.");
                } else if ($('#sortable1 li').length <= 1) {
                    $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
                    alert('You must have at least two banners');
                }
                doSortMe(); //<-- Added call here
            }
        });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/J9eQL/2/